# Is there anyway to login to CAS without the login screen?

Tags: python, cas, python-requests

My university use CAS as a login tool to access the place where professors post homework and assignments. I am trying to build a python script that can catch all the due dates from it and send me a reminder before every due dates. However, I could not manage to get pass the CAS login procedure with the python requests module. Is there anyway I can login to CAS without opening the login page in my browser? Can I pass my username and passwords as parameters to get pass it?

The login screen I am trying to get pass is this
https://netid.rice.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fowlspace-ccm.rice.edu%2Fsakai-login-tool%2Fcontainer

The requests module I am trying to use can be found here:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the code you currently have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go.

1) have your script act like a browser and post your credentials to the cas login form.  This will result in a redirect request to the resource with the CAS ticket.  Honor the redirect request and the you should good to go.

2) If your school has the CAS REST API available you could use that to obtain a TGT and a subsequent ST for the app your trying to access.
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I wasn't really checking this thread. I have found a way to post credentials to the cas login form, by using a python library called requests.The second way looks better though I am not sure if my school will provide that. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

The CAS login cannot be bypassed from outside the protected CAS application - if you find a way the there is a security hole!!!

Comment: Hi, I wasn't trying to bypass the CAS from protected CAS allplication, I was just trying to simplified the process of log in. I have find a way to post credential using a python library called "requests".